# regular expression for some special charaters and number in php

Tags: php, regex

I am looking for a php regex that can contain only , and - chracters.

in short i would like a regex that can match the following:

```
* may contain number
* may contain space
* may contain , -
```

i am making a php script to check if a certain string have the above or not, like a validation check. 
i have tried with this

```
^([\[\]=,{\}\0-9_-]+)$
```

but not working. please someone help me.

Comment: You want to match the actual words "may contain number"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match("#-?\d+(,\d+)?#", "-1,2", $match);
```

Comment: This fails for most valid combinations yet it's been accepted. I guess we all misunderstood the question but @rajesh :(

Answer (score 3):

The `-` literal must be the first or last character in [character classes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php). Otherwise, it's a range indicator:

```
^[0-9 ,-]+$
```

*(Not sure though why you add `=` and other stuff.)*

Answer (score 1):

Try this regular expression:

```
^[\d\s,-]*$
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
^([\ ,0-9-]*)$
```

I offer you using this [site](http://www.strfriend.com/) to see what your regex expose.